# Что означает -apple-system у свойства font-family?

Tags: css

Нашёл в css коде фреймворка Tailwind такую строку:

```
html {
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"
}
```

Что в данном фрагменте делает `-apple-system` и нужен ли он?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"
```

Эта строка объявляет стек системных шрифтов Mac OS,а также стандартные шрифты на всех популярных платформах и браузерах, если использовать font-family, то вам придется каждый раз вызывать полный стек шрифтов , когда вы захотите применить шрифт к элементу, это увеличит размер вашего кода.

`-apple-system` - шрифт (San Francisco) для iOS Safari, MacOS Safari, MacOS Firefox

`BlinkMacSystemFont` - (San Francisco) для  MacOS Chrome

`Segoe UI` - для Windows

Стек шрифтов работает так - если не загрузился 1-й шрифт из списка, браузер попробует загрузить второй и т.д

Все это имеет смысл использовать для того, чтобы ваше приложение не отличалось от среды в которой оно используется, например для сайта это не так актуально.

Если вы все же хотите один раз объявить шрифты через `@font-face` используйте это:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: system;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local(".SFNSText-Light"), local(".HelveticaNeueDeskInterface-Light"), local(".LucidaGrandeUI"), local("Ubuntu Light"), local("Segoe UI Light"), local("Roboto-Light"), local("DroidSans"), local("Tahoma");
}

p {
font-family: "system";
}
```